# MS Access Form - Between

Tags: forms, ms-access

I've created a form and need to make it so that it searches between 2 years.
So for example if the user enters 1980 and 2000, I need all entries to come up which are between those two years. Any help?!
http://imgur.com/bqdFWFB

The same goes for the length. Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: Please add code, and a real question...

Comment: Well, I asked the question because obviously, I don't know how to write the code! Go spend your time being useful and helping people instead of telling people to ask real questions.

Comment: Perhaps I phrased my comment incorrectly. The point of SO is to be a website where people can help you, *yes*, but you need to show *effort*. This effort in writing the code allows people to help you to debug it and teach you - but SO was not made so that people can write code for others. In addition, bad questions occasionally lead to a question ban so I would be wary of that. Sorry for sounding overly harsh above.

Comment: Yea I understand that, but how else can I show effort? I looked it up and couldn't find anything that specifically addressed my question. Not everyone on SO is going to be an experienced coder, so they may need some help to just get started. I know this probably seems like a really 'noob' question, and that's because it is. But I can't go forward if I don't get help, and that's why I came on here. 
No problem :) I'm still trying to sort it out though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sure,

Assuming that your form is bound to the table with the date field that you're filtering on, You could implement your search in the header section of that form.

Using design view, add two unbound text boxes (set their input mask to date/time to allow a datepicker to be used if you want). We'll call them txtDateStart and txtDateEnd.

In the after update for your txtDateEnd control on your form, add some vb code.

```
    Me.Filter = "[dateField] BETWEEN " & me.txtDateStart & " AND " &  me.txtdateEnd 
    me.filteron = true
```

That should be all you need.

Comment: You select the second date control, go to events, and choose 'after update'

Comment: Thanks! :)
Hmmm I end up with this (I'm pretty sure it's right)http://imgur.com/8qroCoq
So I enter 1990 in the left box and 2000 in the right box, but it doesn't filter them out when I run my query.

Comment: I believe there is a "..." dialog when you click the after update event for a control. you are close! when you click that dialog, it will ask you if you want to make a macro or do it in VB code. Choose the code builder option and paste the code in my answer in the block provided. Make sure your controls were named appropriately

Comment: Ah ok I see! 
Ok well I made it into code and changed the names. The column where all the years are held (which need to be filtered) is named 'Year', the first box is named Year1, and the second is Year2.
When I input years, it still shows me all of my data.. :(
http://imgur.com/HXD7uVs

Comment: change the first line to Me.Filter = "[dateField] BETWEEN #" & me.txtDateStart & "# AND #" &  me.txtdateEnd & "#"  . if that doesnt work, try separating the BETWEEN clause into two >= and <= clauses ( roughly year >= #me.startdate# AND year <=  #me.enddate)

Comment: Like this? Still doesn't work. Could it be something to do with my query?
http://imgur.com/WlsrlHm

Comment: That looks right to me. Try adding Form.Refresh and Form.Requery after those lines of code. Is the record source for the form bound to your table? go to the data tab and select the source

Comment: Yea it is! I don't see why it won't work! >:(
Thanks for all your help by the way! :)
http://imgur.com/gedTPms